# Windows CMD reset PATH variable to default

Tags: cmd.exe, environment-variables

I have a question that someone surely must have come across, but maybe I'm not using the right search terms.
I wish to reset the PATH variable in a command prompt to the default.
So, for example, I open a prompt

```
set PATH=C:\someting\bin;%PATH%
REM do something
set PATH=<original when window was opened>
REM do something else
```

Two solutions I see:

**1. This clumsiness**

```
set ORIPATH=%PATH%
set PATH=C:\someting\bin;%PATH%
REM do something
set PATH=%ORIPATH%
REM do something else
```

**2. Separate cmds**

```
cmd.exe /k
set PATH=C:\someting\bin;%PATH%
REM do something
exit
cmd.exe/k
set PATH=C:\someting_else\bin;%PATH%
REM do something else
exit
```

This seems to have the distinct disadvantage that other environment settings get lost.

Is there a better way, and if so, what?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find SS64 on [`SETLOCAL`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) and [`ENDLOCAL`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) to be of interest.

Comment: This seems like a decent solution; if you want to phrase this into an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of the command prompt in Windows allow you to maintain local copies of the environment with limited scope; the scopes are signalled using the `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` commands. By bracketing a code block in a batch file with these commands, you ensure that any changes to the environment that you make (unless you use `SET /M`) will be non-persistent, and will revert when the scope is exited:

```
SET FOO=BAR
...do stuff...
ECHO %FOO%
REM FOO still equals BAR unless stuff changed it
SETLOCAL
...do more stuff...
ECHO %FOO%
REM FOO still equals BAR unless more stuff changed it
SET FOO=QUUX
... do still more stuff...
ECHO %FOO%
REM FOO still equals QUUX unless still more stuff changed it
ENDLOCAL
ECHO %FOO%
REM FOO is back to equalling BAR, or whatever stuff changed it to
```