# How to call programs from cmd directly without adding their paths to PATH variable on windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables, path

Suppose I installed a new package with `someProgram` in it:
`myNewPackageDir/bin/someProgram`

If I want to accessing it from cmd using only its name (example: `someProgram --option1 a --option2 b --option3 c`), I would have to append `someProgram`'s folder to the PATH variable:
`setx PATH "%path%;myNewPackageDir\bin"`

I keep installing many packages on windows through winget, and everytime a new package is installed, i have to add this new program's folder path to the `PATH` variable so i can call it from cmd directly.

Any other way around this? Is there a better approach? My `PATH` variable is really long now(>1000 characters), and I don't want to keep adding **every** new program's directory to the `PATH` variable. The whole reason i add it to the `PATH` variable is so that i can call it directly, but this process is becoming cumbersome with more packages being installed.

**So how do i call programs directly without adding it to my `PATH` variable?**

(Also, I am using Windows 10.)

Comment: @Robert I do use `\ ` , but i wrote `/` here by mistake, but that's not the point.

Comment: "So how do I call programs directly without adding it to my PATH variable?" - You create a system variable, that contains the path to the application, and then add the variable to the PATH variable.  You would have a similar issue on Linux

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1426664/windows-cmd-reset-path-variable-to-default?rq=1) is a nice alternative if you are attempting to do this for scripting reasons.

Comment: Also type `doskey /?`. You load your alias at Command Prompt startup by specifying a batch or command at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` and create the `AutoRun` string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
All I wanted to achieve was being able to call someProgram.exe directly without adding it to my PATH variable.
So I created a folder called `C:\Shortcuts` and added a shorcut to `someProgram.exe`:
`someProgram.lnk`.
I added this `C:\Shorcuts` folder to my Path variable: `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Shorcuts"`
Now, from any directory, i can simply call:
`someProgram --option1 a --option2 b c` and it will work.

From now on, i just have to drop in shortcuts to the programs i want to call directly into this new folder, and I saved a lot of characters on my `PATH` variable

EDIT: this doesn't work correctly all the time, for example, python doesn't work exactly the way i want it to if i am calling if from a shortcut, so i would have to add its directory to the path variable. But most of the time, it works pretty well

Comment: Also, you have to add .LNK to your `pathtext` variable to avoid typing .lnk everytime you are trying to call someProgram.lnk

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the start command:

start "" "SomeProgram.exe"

- The first quotes are for the program title if you want to specify

The other method is to add the program in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\

Inside "App Paths" create a key with the name of the program + extension that the user should use open the program, ex: SomeProgram.exe

Inside the "SomeProgram.exe" key create new "String Value" called "Path" and specify the path to the program there (only the path not path + prorgramname).

Ex: C:\Program Files\Techsmith\Camtasia 9\

That's it....